# How to retrieve results while the program is executed with a bash script

Tags: bash, qt, shell

I'm working with Qt and when I press a button connected to a bash script (with QProcess) it will execute a project done with C language. After that I want to retrieve the results (output of the program). How can I do that?

Comment: -1 No code. Nothing you've tried before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the script and program sends the output to the command line, simply use the functions provided by the QProcess class: -

```
QProcess proc;
proc.start("pathToProgram.exe"); // call the script or program to launch
proc.waitForFinished();
QString output = proc.readAllStandardOutput();

// do something with the result - let's just print it to the console
qDebug() << output;
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon in the first line. ;)

Answer (score 0):

QProcess inherits from QIODevice so you can use methods like:

```
read()
readLine()
getChar()
```

[look for more here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html#details)

Comment: This is bad idea because QProcess has convenience methods. I think you could read the link yourself that you suggested. :p

Comment: @LaszloPapp: You're right that QProcess has convenience methods, but OTOH isn't it one of the 'features' of inheritance, that you can work with inherited object using general interface? Besides, the sample code on this page uses `ReadAll` from `QIODevice` so it should work as expected. I don't say you're wrong, I just don't see a reason to avoid using interfaces from base class.

Comment: There is no ReadAll, but readAll. ;) But yeah, the reason is to avoid the boilerplate yourself.

Comment: I don't get it - in good old days it was called `code reuse`, now it's a `boilerplate` :) ?

Comment: In my good old days, it was called boilerplate. Try to write readAll yourself and you will see it is longer than just calling readAll.